# List Cache Behavior

Tags: performance, linked-list, ocaml, internals

[OCaml From the Ground Up](https://ocamlbook.org/lists-and-structural-recursion/) states that ...

> At the machine level, a linked list is a pair of a head value and a pointer to the tail.

I have heard that linked lists (in imperative languages) tend to be slow because of cache misses, memory overhead and pointer chasing. I am curious if OCaml's garbage collector or memory management system avoids any of these issues, and if they do what sort of techniques or optimizations they employ internally that might be different from linked lists in other languages.

Comment: Your question is somehow ill-asked because it's very vague. "Are they not as big a deal as they are made out to be" without any reference about how much a big deal it is made depends entirely on reader, and similarly "decently fast"'s meaning can depend a lot on the context. I would suggest either adding some details (what do *you* mean by fast, what do you need / expect) or simply rephrasing your question as "what are the optimizations I can expect from OCaml's memory model?" (or something similar).

Comment: @BlackBeans Thanks for your suggestions. I have edited the post to try and remove the vagueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linked list is indeed a horrible structure to iterate over in general.

But this is mitigated a lot by the way OCaml allocates memory and how lists are created most of the time.

In OCaml the GC allocates a large block of memory as it's (minor) heap and maintains a pointer to the end of the used portion. An allocation simply increases the pointer by the needed amount of memory.

Combine that with the fact that most of the time lists are constructed in a very short time. Often the list creation is the only thing allocating memory. Think of `List.map` for example, or `List.rev`. That will produce a list where the nodes of the list are contiguous in memory. So the linked list isn't jumping all over the address space but is rather contained on a small chunk. This allows caching to work far better than you would expect for a linked list. Iterating the list will actually access memory sequentially.

The above means that a lot of lists are much more ordered than in other languages. And a lot of the time lists are temporary and will be purely in cache. It performs a lot better than it ought to.

There is another layer to this. In OCaml the garbage collector is a generational GC. New values are created on the minor heap which is scanned frequently. Temporary values are thus quickly reclaimed. Values that remain alive on the minor heap are copied to the major heap, which is scanned less frequent. The copy operation compacts the values, eliminating any holes caused by values that are no longer alive. This will bring list nodes closer together again if it had gaps in it in the first place. The same thing happens when the major heap is scanned, the memory is compacted bringing values that where allocated close in time nearer together.

While none of that guarantees that lists will be contiguous in memory it seems to avoid a lot of the bad effects associated with linked lists in other languages. None the less you shouldn't use lists when you need to iterate over data, or worse access the n-th node, frequently. Use an array instead. Appending is bad too unless your list is small (and will overflow the stack for large lists). Due to the later you often build a list in reverse, adding items to the front instead of appending at the end, and then reverse the list as final step. And that final `List.rev` will give you a perfectly contiguous list.

Answer (score 3):

OCaml manages its own memory, it calls system-level memory allocation and deallocation primitives in its own terms (e.g. it can allocate a big chunk of heap memory during the start of the program, and manage OCaml values on it), so if the compiler and/or the runtime knows that you are allocating a list of a fixed sized, it can arrange for the cells to be close to each other in memory. And since there is no pointer type in the language itself, it can move values around during garbage collection, to avoid memory fragmentation, something a language like C or C++ cannot do (or with great effort to maintain the abstraction while allowing moves).

Those are general pointers about how garbage collected languages (imperative or not) may optimize memory management, but [Understanding the Garbage Collector](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/garbage-collector.html) has more details about how the garbage collector actually works in OCaml.